# how to select a particular table and print its data using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following code which i use to get results from a site called ssllabs,com

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
req  = requests.get("https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=drtest.test.sentinelcloud.com")
data = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
report_tables=soup.find_all('table',class_='reportTable')
print report_tables
```

this returns me following tables:

[image: My data is in the table indicated with arrorow]

Now my data is in the table i indicated . The structure inside of this table looks like

```
<table class="reportTable">
   \n
   <thead>
      \n
      <tr>
         \n
         <td class="tableHead" colspan="3">Cipher Suites (SSL 3+ suites in server-preferred order; deprecated and SSL 2 suites at the end)</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
   </thead>
   \n
   <tbody>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256\n                                        (<code>0xc02f</code>)\n                                                            \xa0 <span class="greySmall"> ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) \xa0 FS</span>\n</td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">128</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384\n                                        (<code>0xc030</code>)\n                                                            \xa0 <span class="greySmall"> ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) \xa0 FS</span>\n</td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">256</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256\n                                        (<code>0x9e</code>)\n                                 \xa0\n                                    <span class="greySmall">\n<span title="p: 256, g: 1, Ys: 256">DH 2048 bits</span> \xa0 FS</span>\n</td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">128</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384\n                                        (<code>0x9f</code>)\n                                 \xa0\n                                    <span class="greySmall">\n<span title="p: 256, g: 1, Ys: 256">DH 2048 bits</span> \xa0 FS</span>\n</td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">256</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256\n                                        (<code>0xc027</code>)\n                                                            \xa0 <span class="greySmall"> ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) \xa0 FS</span>\n</td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">128</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA\n                                        (<code>0xc013</code>)\n                                                            \xa0 <span class="greySmall"> ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) \xa0 FS</span>\n</td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">128</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384\n                                        (<code>0xc028</code>)\n                                                            \xa0 <span class="greySmall"> ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) \xa0 FS</span>\n</td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">256</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA\n                                        (<code>0xc014</code>)\n                                                            \xa0 <span class="greySmall"> ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) \xa0 FS</span>\n</td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">256</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256\n                                        (<code>0x67</code>)\n                                 \xa0\n                                    <span class="greySmall">\n<span title="p: 256, g: 1, Ys: 256">DH 2048 bits</span> \xa0 FS</span>\n</td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">128</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA\n                                        (<code>0x33</code>)\n                                 \xa0\n                                    <span class="greySmall">\n<span title="p: 256, g: 1, Ys: 256">DH 2048 bits</span> \xa0 FS</span>\n</td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">128</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256\n                                        (<code>0x6b</code>)\n                                 \xa0\n                                    <span class="greySmall">\n<span title="p: 256, g: 1, Ys: 256">DH 2048 bits</span> \xa0 FS</span>\n</td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">256</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA\n                                        (<code>0x39</code>)\n                                 \xa0\n                                    <span class="greySmall">\n<span title="p: 256, g: 1, Ys: 256">DH 2048 bits</span> \xa0 FS</span>\n</td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">256</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA\n                                        (<code>0xc012</code>)\n                                                            \xa0 <span class="greySmall"> ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) \xa0 FS</span>\n</td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">112</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256\n                                        (<code>0x9c</code>)\n                                                                \n                    \n                </td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">128</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384\n                                        (<code>0x9d</code>)\n                                                                \n                    \n                </td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">256</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256\n                                        (<code>0x3c</code>)\n                                                                \n                    \n                </td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">128</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256\n                                        (<code>0x3d</code>)\n                                                                \n                    \n                </td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">256</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA\n                                        (<code>0x2f</code>)\n                                                                \n                    \n                </td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">128</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA\n                                        (<code>0x35</code>)\n                                                                \n                    \n                </td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">256</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA\n                                        (<code>0x88</code>)\n                                 \xa0\n                                    <span class="greySmall">\n<span title="p: 256, g: 1, Ys: 256">DH 2048 bits</span> \xa0 FS</span>\n</td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">256</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA\n                                        (<code>0x84</code>)\n                                                                \n                    \n                </td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">256</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA\n                                        (<code>0x45</code>)\n                                 \xa0\n                                    <span class="greySmall">\n<span title="p: 256, g: 1, Ys: 256">DH 2048 bits</span> \xa0 FS</span>\n</td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">128</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA\n                                        (<code>0x41</code>)\n                                                                \n                    \n                </td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">128</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
      <tr class="tableRow">
         \n
         <td class="tableLeft">\n                                            TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA\n                                        (<code>0xa</code>)\n                                                                \n                    \n                </td>
         \n
         <td class="tableRight">112</td>
         \n
      </tr>
      \n
   </tbody>
   \n
</table>
```

I need to get inside 'tbody' and extract all tableLeft values and place them in a list . 
My question :

```
1. How to select that particular reportTable at line 493 in picture.
2. How to extract the values (TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384.......................) and put in LIST
```

Comment: 1. `report_tables[4]` 2. `report_tables[4].find_all('td', class_='tableLeft')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @furas' comment slightly, as `report_tables[4]` assumes it will always be the 5th table:

```
req = requests.get("https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=drtest.test.sentinelcloud.com")
data = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for found_table in soup.find_all('table', class_='reportTable'):
    if 'Cipher Suites' in found_table.get_text():
        values = found_table.find_all('td', class_='tableLeft')
        entries = []
        for row in values:
            entries.append(row.get_text())
        print entries
```

Checking for 'Cipher Suites' (though you could use a more complete title if needs be) should help you get the correct table more consistently.

You could simple use `values` as an output, but using `get_text()` helps us remove some of the html that you likely won't need. `entries` will contain the values you require, but you might need to look into functions like `strip` to clear whitespace from the results.

**PRODUCED RESULT:**

```
[u'\n                                            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256\n                                        (0xc02f)\n                                                            \xa0  ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) \xa0 FS\n', u'\n                                            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384\n                                        (0xc030)\n                                                            \xa0  ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) \xa0 FS\n', u'\n                                            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256\n                                        (0x9e)\n                                 \xa0\n                                    \nDH 2048 bits \xa0 FS\n', u'\n                                            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384\n                                        (0x9f)\n                                 \xa0\n                                    \nDH 2048 bits \xa0 FS\n', u'\n                                            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256\n                                        (0xc027)\n                                                            \xa0  ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) \xa0 FS\n', u'\n                                            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA\n                                        (0xc013)\n                                                            \xa0  ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) \xa0 FS\n', u'\n                                            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384\n                                        (0xc028)\n                                                            \xa0  ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) \xa0 FS\n', u'\n                                            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA\n                                        (0xc014)\n                                                            \xa0  ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) \xa0 FS\n', u'\n                                            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256\n                                        (0x67)\n                                 \xa0\n                                    \nDH 2048 bits \xa0 FS\n', u'\n                                            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA\n                                        (0x33)\n                                 \xa0\n                                    \nDH 2048 bits \xa0 FS\n', u'\n                                            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256\n                                        (0x6b)\n                                 \xa0\n                                    \nDH 2048 bits \xa0 FS\n', u'\n                                            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA\n                                        (0x39)\n                                 \xa0\n                                    \nDH 2048 bits \xa0 FS\n', u'\n                                            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA\n                                        (0xc012)\n                                                            \xa0  ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA) \xa0 FS\n', u'\n                                            TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256\n                                        (0x9c)\n                                                                \n                    \n                ', u'\n                                            TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384\n                                        (0x9d)\n                                                                \n                    \n                ', u'\n                                            TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256\n                                        (0x3c)\n                                                                \n                    \n                ', u'\n                                            TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256\n                                        (0x3d)\n                                                                \n                    \n                ', u'\n                                            TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA\n                                        (0x2f)\n                                                                \n                    \n                ', u'\n                                            TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA\n                                        (0x35)\n                                                                \n                    \n                ', u'\n                                            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA\n                                        (0x88)\n                                 \xa0\n                                    \nDH 2048 bits \xa0 FS\n', u'\n                                            TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA\n                                        (0x84)\n                                                                \n                    \n                ', u'\n                                            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA\n                                        (0x45)\n                                 \xa0\n                                    \nDH 2048 bits \xa0 FS\n', u'\n                                            TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA\n                                        (0x41)\n                                                                \n                    \n                ', u'\n                                            TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA\n                                        (0xa)\n                                                                \n                    \n                ']
```

**EDIT:** to expand this in line with @PadraicCunningham's comments, we can remove the whitespace and return the first value as follows:

```
for found_table in soup.find_all('table', class_='reportTable'):
    if 'Cipher Suites' in found_table.get_text():
        vals = [td.text.split()[0] for td in found_table.select("td.tableLeft")]
        print vals
        break
```

Comment: I have updated the RESULT , please check . i need to remove all the extra charecters and put the result in list

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am using "Cipher Suites (SSL 3+ suites in server-preferred order; deprecated and SSL 2 suites at the end)" which i know is unique in every way. How can remove the extra chars

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think he meant the fourth index. I basically did the same as furas and used `report_tables[4]` then used a for-loop like this: `for td in report_tables.find_all('td', class_='tableLeft'):
 for line in td:
  my_data.append(line)`.

Comment: @Kittystone, `table = soup.find_all('table',class_='reportTable', limit=5)[-1][td.text.split()[0] for td in table.select("td.tableLeft")]` presuming you just want the `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` etc..

Comment: @PadraicCunningham How exactly to use this in my code ?

Comment: @kittystone, exactly as posted

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It says `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` after for

Comment: @Kittystone, there is no SyntaxError in the code, you are running both on separate lines yes?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham As it is http://pastebin.com/TMpjgrQi

Comment: You have it all on one line, the list comp should be in it's own line and that is what holds the data i.e `data = [td.text.split()[0] for td in table.select("td.tableLeft")]`

Comment: got it thank you so much :)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham apologies for the delayed response - you're absolutely right in each of your comments. I've tried to incorporate them into the answer, thankyou.

Comment: You also probably want to break after finding the table, no point going further once you find it.